# describing layers in costmap .yaml files

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so, we have 3 .yaml files:

1. common_costmap.yaml
2. global_costmap.yaml
3. local_costmap.yaml

For example, let global_costmap has these layers:

```
  plugins:
      - {name: static,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
      - {name: inflation,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
      - {name: sonar,             type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
```

where am i supposed to describe layers params, in global_costmap or common costmap or in both?

i mean these lines:

```
static:
   map_topic: /map
   subscribe_to_updates: true

inflation:
   inflation_radius: 0.4

sonar:
   frame: range_sensor_frame
   topics: ["/sensor_us", "/sensor_ir"]
   no_readings_timeout: 2.0
   clear_on_max_reading: false
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330990/describing-layers-in-costmap-.yaml-files/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either choose  `common_costmap.yaml` or `global_costmap.yaml`. Obviously, `local_costmap.yaml` makes no sense.

It is important to load them to the correct namespace, i.e. into `global_costmap`, whether you have it in `common_costmap.yaml` or `global_costmap.yaml`, as it is shown on [this example](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Creating_a_Launch_File_for_the_Navigation_Stack).

Whether you put it in `common_costmap.yaml` or `global_costmap.yaml` should be decided whether you actually have the same configuration of a layer for both, the global and local costmap, or not.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2